Using a TaskCompletionSource<T> to asynchronously wait without locking?
I have a class that processes a never ending stream of data. I also have external components that would like to asynchronously sample the processed data from time to time in an ad-hoc fashion.
Since it could be a while before the "next item" is processed, I'd like the data inspector components to "await" the item so they don't block. They could be any number of different data inspecting components, and if multiple inspectors are awaiting an item, it's fine if they all get the same item instance.
The data items are very large, so they get disposed immediately after processing for memory efficiency. And I don't want to do anything that will delay this (like posting the data to a channel or something like that)
I have the implementation below using a TaskCompletionSource and locks to make sure that the tcs works on different threads. It seems to work okay, but I'd like to do this in a lock-less way if possible.
public class DataProcessor
{
  private object _sampleDataLock = new object();
  private TaskCompletionSource<Data> _sampleData;
  private Thread _processThread;

  public DataProcessor()
  {
     _processThread = new(ProcessDataLoop);
     _processThread.Start();
  }

  void ProcessDataLoop()
  {
      while (true)
      {
         var processedData = ProcessNextData();
         
         //This code in the lock is what I wonder about
         lock (_sampleDataLock)
         {
            _sampleData?.SetResult(processedData.Clone());
            _sampleData = null;
         }

        processedData.Dispose();
      }
  }

  public Task<Data> SampleData(TimeSpan timeout)
  {
    // This is the code I'm wondering how to write without a lock
    lock (_sampleDataLock)
    {
      _sampleData ??= new TaskCompletionSource<Data>();
      return _sampleData.Task.WithTimeout(timeout);
    }
  }
}

public class DataInspector
{
    private DataProcessor _processor;

    public async Task InspectData()
    {
       //wait up to 30s for an item
       var data = await _processor.SampleData(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
       // look at data
    }
}


I'm wondering if there's a way to do the same thing without locking.

Use a "subscription" (event) service and notify the "subscribers" (who attach / detach) instead of having them poll you. They can all read, and if you need more, use concurrent stacks or queues.  The subscribers decide which wake up calls to react to.

Have you considered using Channel<T> instead?

When the program makes a call to "inspect the data," is it a requirement that it wait for the next set of data? It would be much simpler (trivial, really) to inspect the last data that was processed.

@johnwu, yes it should be the next data, since the previous data may be stale. I would also rather not return the last data, because then I'd have to clone every data item, and these are large objects.

@GerrySchmitz this basically is an event subscription model. The subscriber calls GetData when it wants a data item and the next item is provided. I could create an event handler or register or delegate, but then every caller would do the same work to await an item being produced

@dai how would a channel help the data inspector get an item? Remember, I don't need any sort of queue or buffer, just the next item, if it ever arrives.

Sounds like you want ReactiveX then: https://reactivex.io/ + https://github.com/dotnet/reactive (this has nothing to do with ReactJS btw)

@dai yes, this code used RX at one time, but it was not memory efficient, and every observer duplicated the code to sample the item. I don't really want anyone to be able to observe all the data as it is processed.

Would a rendezvous channel without buffer work in your scenario?

@JohnV There's nothing inherently memory-inefficient about ReactiveX - but due to how ReactiveX works in C# it's easy to end-up with memory-leaks if people don't know what they're doing.

The fact "everyone does the same work" doesn't prevent the subscriber(s) from using a common handler. "Pulling" is not an "event". Pushing a notification in response to new data is.

I'd like to do this in a lock-less way if possible - why? Have you measured the performance and determined that the lock is a performance issue?

You could use a traditional event handler. Readers would subscribe to the event, clone the data needed, then unsubscribe before returning. The TaskCompletionSource is handled only by the SampleData method (passed to the handler by closure) and not touched by the main execution loop.
public class DataProcessor
{
    public class DataEventArgs : EventArgs
    {
        public Data Data { get; set; }
    }

    public event EventHandler<DataEventArgs> DataReady;

    private Thread _processThread;
    
    public DataProcessor()
    {
        _processThread = new(ProcessDataLoop);
        _processThread.Start();
    }
    
    
    void OnDataReady(Data data) => DataReady?.Invoke(this, new DataEventArgs { Data = data });
    
    void ProcessDataLoop()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            var processedData = ProcessNextData();
            this.OnDataReady(processedData);
            processedData.Dispose();
        }
    }

    public async Task<Data> SampleData(TimeSpan timeout)
    {
        var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<Data>();
        void Handler(object sender, DataEventArgs e) 
        {
            tcs.SetResult(e.Data.Clone());
            this.DataReady -= Handler;
        }
      
        this.DataReady += Handler;
        return await tcs.Task;
    }
}


Instead of your approach, you can use system waitable handles to wait on, (for example, manual reset events), and you can store your objects in a concurrent queue.
Your consumers then follow a pattern of trying to dequeue as many objects from the concurrent queue as possible, then asynchroneously waiting for the event to pulse. The producer pulses the event every time they push a new item to the collection.
If instead you want to avoid reinventing the wheel, here's a solid implementation of an async collection with maximum number of items and producer/consumer queueing through async functions: https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx/blob/master/src/Nito.AsyncEx.Coordination/AsyncCollection.cs

That's much more complicated than I need. Most of the time, there is no consumer at all, and when there is a consumer, it's not trying to consume multiple items, it just wants any item.
